# Is it possible to test a js function which returns nothing with chai?

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, chai

```js
async executeEventEndSuccess(statusData) {
        if (storageType.toUpperCase() !== common.Blob) {
            let appStatus = status.getStatus(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, statusData.excutionId);
            uploadHelper.renameFileOnEndEvent(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, statusData.excutionId);
            appStatus.forEach(async ele => {
                if (ele.executionID === parseInt(statusData.excutionId) && ele.tenant === statusData.tenantId && ele.panel === statusData.viewerId && ele.tableName === common.type.panelWatch) {
                    try {
                        const updateDataPanelStatus = await panelStatusData.updatePanelStatus(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, ele.path)
                        eventRepo.updatePanelStatus(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, updateDataPanelStatus);
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                };
            });
        }

        try {
            console.log(statusData.tenants);
            
            await eventRepo.executeEndProcedure(statusData);
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Here i need to test whether appStatus is existing in my executeEventEndSuccess function or not? I need to perform unit testing for this function??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes** I would personally perform unit testing for this function.

And **Yes** it's possible to hook into this function in some backwards ways, through tools like `mock-require` or other test/design hacks.

It looks like this function does a number of important things that would benefit from test coverage, in order to verify that it works, as well as protect against regressions:

- Rename File if not a `common.Blob`

```
if (storageType.toUpperCase() !== common.Blob) {
...
uploadHelper.renameFileOnEndEvent(
  statusData.tenantId, 
  statusData.viewerId, 
  statusData.excutionId
);
```

- Performs status matching

```
if (ele.executionID === parseInt(statusData.excutionId) && ele.tenant === statusData.tenantId && ele.panel === statusData.viewerId && ele.tableName === common.type.panelWatch) {
```

- Performs (distributed?) status updates

```
const updateDataPanelStatus = await panelStatusData.updatePanelStatus(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, ele.path)
                        eventRepo.updatePanelStatus(statusData.tenantId, statusData.viewerId, updateDataPanelStatus);
```

- Performs end procedure

```
await eventRepo.executeEndProcedure(statusData);
```

---

Each one of these actions seems pretty important!

consider the case of the status matching.  Without tests, suppose you verify everything manually, click through the transaction ensure everything is working.  A couple months later another engineer comes back, doesn't think that `ele.tenant` is used anymore and removes the check from the conditional.  Without tests, there is no feedback on this change,  the feature isn't protected, the client isn't protected and the engineer isn't protected!

Additionally, consider the renaming feature.  That seems pretty important,  if I was working in this code base I would personally like tests covering that this feature is working, and be protected against introducing a regression that might cause renames not to occur.

Finally, Tests will help you verify the features and flows work during development, and will do so with less overhead and quicker than manually executing these flows.

The hard part is now actually testing it :) As it stands its difficult to isolate the important looking pieces of functionality I listed above.  You could refactor to help expose that functionality and make it directly testable, or you could use some sort of mocking/patch framework to allow you to hook into the functionality and assert on calls.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but can you show me how to test status updates code using mocha chai or sinon framework?? It would be very helpful to me..